# how to convert typedef basic_string<char> string to byte array in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, string, java-native-interface

I am trying to pass cpp string to java android using JNI.

```
void Endpoint::utilLogWrite(int prmLevel,
                const string &prmSender,
                const string &prmMsg)
```

so when i read the prmMsg from java using JNI i get exception.
The  below exception occurs while converting that cpp string to java String.

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION

I have no control over JNIMethods.so searching stackoverflow tells instead of sending cpp string prefer sending byte array.

The variable prmMsg is of type **typedef basic_string**
so how to convert this typedef basic_string    string to byte array.In java we have simple method

> String.toBytes()

.But IN CPP how can i achieve it.

Comment: What exception occurs?  How are you passing the string?

Comment: What do you mean by "send"? Do you mean a function call?

Comment: @NathanOliver JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte this is the exception which occurs

Comment: @user2079303 no i already have a function which uses string parameter ,instead of string parameter i like to have byte array as parameter

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing to get the exception nor what code you are proposing changing nor what you mean by byte array. It seems like you are blocked by a bug in 3rd-party code: It can't handle characters that UTF-8 encodes with 4 code units because it is inappropriately using JNI functions that require the Modified UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I think you are saying you are calling utilLogWrite. Can you call it successfully with just Basic Latin text?

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes .Im calling utilLogWrite.wat do you mean by basic latin text??

Comment: I meant to say Basic Latin _characters_ as a simpler form of [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). Android generally uses the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set. What does utilLogWrite use? It should be documented. It seems that it is choking on some the codepoints that UTF-8 encodes differently than Modified UTF-8 encoded them. I suggest trying just Basic Latin characters because they would be encoded to the same bytes. Of find the documentation and it might say to use Modified UTF-8.

Comment: BTW—You aren't trying to shove non-text data through a text function, are you?

Comment: @TomBlodget it just plain message which is XOR

Comment: @TomBlodget the string i use of the  type typedef basic_string <char>

Comment: Oh, so try this manual experiment. Take a message encoded in UTF-8, XOR the bytes and then try to decode it as UTF-8. Depending on the data, you'll find that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

"input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte": Yep, UTF-8 is not the same as Modified UTF-8, which is a crutch JNI offers [and, in some places (class paths and member names, etc), demands]. So, I like your approach of using Java to do any character encoding conversions.

To create a byte array, call `NewByteArray`. To fill it, call `SetByteArrayRegion`. To get jbytes out of a std::string, call `data` and cast.

```
std::string s = "\xF0\x9F\x9A\xB2";

// jbyte and char are the same size
const auto output = env->NewByteArray(s.length());
env->SetByteArrayRegion(output, 0, s.length(), reinterpret_cast<const jbyte *>(s.data()));
return output; // return or release output
```

Comment: i have no control over that JNI part as it is a third party component.They  have a script which does the JNI part.so instead of passing string to JNI i like to send byte from CPP side.

Comment: Java String.toBytes is of type Java byte[], which in JNI is of type jbytearray. This answer shows how to copy from std::string to a new jbytearray. You need to use JNI methods to do that.